# getting error while installing magento

Tags: php, magento

I am getting error:

> extension=php_intl.dll not found

I have uncommented it from `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you reload your apache/PHP services after doing changes?

Create php script (in example info.php) with the code:

```
<?php
// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();
?>
```

Place it on your web server and check for results if you can find php_intl exntetion there.

Comment: Thanks for the guiding